# How to set a interface to two separate other interfaces, without merging (Typescript)

Tags: typescript, inheritance, types, extends

Im very very new to typescript, but lets say I have something like this:

```
class Foo{
  options: fooOptionsObj;
  constructor(options: fooOptionsObj){
    this.options = options;
  }
  sayMessage(){
      console.log(`I am number${this.options.position}, and I say ${this.options.message}`);
  }
}

interface fooOptionsObj{
  message: string;
  position: number;
}
```

Then I can make a subclass of `Foo`, and use `fooOptionsObj` to pass in the options

```
class SubFoo extends Foo{
  subOptions: subFooOptionsObj;
  constructor(superOptions: fooOptionsObj, subOptions: subFooOptionsObj){
      super(superOptions);
      this.subOptions = subOptions;
  }
  draw(){
      drawSqaure(0, 0, this.subOptions.size, this.subOptions.size, this.subOptions.color);//say thats a function
  }
}

interface subFooOptionsObj{
    color:string;
    size:number
}
```

But if I wanted to make another:

```
class DifferentSubFoo extends Foo{
...
}
```

I would need to pass in the super arguments different from the sub arguments, which could get confusing.

I would want only one argument, an `options` object, of type whateverClassYourUsingOptionsObj. Something like this:

```
class ThreeLetters{
  options: fooOptionsObj|barOptionsObj;
  constructor(options: fooOptionsObj|barOptionsObj){
    this.options = options;
  }
  sayMessage(){
    console.log(this.options.message)
  }
}

class Foo extends ThreeLetters{
  constructor(options: fooOptionsObj){
    super(options)
  }
  returnBol(): boolean{
    return this.options.bool;
  }
}

class Bar extends ThreeLetters{
  constructor(options: barOptionsObj){
    super(options);
  }
  sayNumber(){
    console.log(this.options.num);
  }
}

interface fooOptionsObj{
  message: string;
  bool: boolean;  
}
interface barOptionsObj{
  message: string;
  num: number;
}
```

However, this doesn't work, because `barOptionsObj` doesn't have a `bool`, and `fooOptionsObj` doesn't have a `num`, even though they shouldn't need one. This is because inside of `ThreeLetters`, the `options` type is `barOptionsObj|fooOptionsObj`, even though it will only ever be one or the other (for an instance). How would I get around this, so that I would need only 1 `options` object?

Answer (score 0):

With the example code as given, I'm going to assume that you want your class hierarchy toform a valid [subtype hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle); that is, you want to be able to use an instance of `Foo` or `Bar` wherever an instance of `ThreeLetters` is expected.

If so, the way I'd proceed is to narrow the type of the `options` property of the subclasses.  This can be done by [`declare`-ing the property in each subclass](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#the-usedefineforclassfields-flag-and-the-declare-property-modifier) which ensures this information only affects the static type system and not the emitted JavaScript.

I'd also probably widen your base options type to something less specific than the union of the options of the known subclasses, unless you know for sure you'd like to limit subclasses to some enumerated list of options types.

Here's the code for the base class:

```
interface BaseOptions {
  message: string;
}

class ThreeLetters {
  readonly options: BaseOptions; // readonly to avoid unsound writes
  constructor(options: BaseOptions) {
    this.options = options;
  }
  sayMessage() {
    console.log(this.options.message)
  }
}
```

Note that I made `options` a `readonly` property, since you'd probably like to prevent someone from grabbing a `Foo`, widening it to a `ThreeLetters` and then writing a `BaseOptions` to it:

```
const tl: ThreeLetters = new Foo({ message: "", bool: true });
const badFooOptions = { message: "", oopsie: 123 };
tl.options = badFooOptions; // error because options is readonly
```

And now for the subclasses:

```
interface FooOptionsObj {
  message: string;
  bool: boolean;
}
class Foo extends ThreeLetters {
  declare options: FooOptionsObj; // narrow
  constructor(options: FooOptionsObj) {
    super(options)
  }
  returnBol(): boolean {
    return this.options.bool;
  }
}
```

and

```
interface BarOptionsObj {
  message: string;
  num: number;
}
class Bar extends ThreeLetters {
  declare options: BarOptionsObj; // narrow
  constructor(options: BarOptionsObj) {
    super(options);
  }
  sayNumber() {
    console.log(this.options.num);
  }
}
```

Now there's no errors and things should hopefully work as expected.  Hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-c158gVtosdi1hujXAYYBLACMACYAMwZfhgURNL59ybdmHNXjIAD0u+QIEIZygUHcyGAME+CQvpCPna0uhABiAA)